# Wrong number of children items returned in join fetch on JPA

Tags: list, jpa, join, set, fetch

I have a JPA OneToMany association

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "playlist", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@IndexColumn(name = "intSequence")
private List<Track> tracks;
```

in class Album.

When I am using join fetch to load the tracks of the album, I get 3 identical tracks into memory while there are actually 3 different tracks for the album in the database, which happens to be the last track in the mysql database.
  It will work if I change the List to Set -- I get all 3 tracks and things work. I did lots of googling and JPA documentations, no clue so far.  Can someone give me some clue.

Comment: Are you sure your `intSequence` column has proper values in the database?

Comment: should that matter ?  they all seem to have 0s

Comment: "It will work if I change the List to Set". Can you please also post how `equals()` and `hashCode()` has been implemented?